# Account activation mobile and web

Tags: mobile-application, registration

Our application can be accessed throught mobile and web. We require verification of email. We will send email with link for activation through web and code for mobile app. I have question regarding this use case

- do you thing some users would like to register throught web and finish the activation via mobile, I can imagine the other way round is fairly possible.
- in mobile app after the registration dialog the dialog awaiting activation code will wait until the user will enter the code or will dismiss the dialog. In case of dismiss would you prefer to have possibility to invoke special dialog for entering the activation code or do you prefer to create new registration from scratch.

Dialog awaiting activation code will warn user in case of cancel so he will need to create new registration afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Offer both methods, accept both at any time

You send an email saying...

> To verify your account, click the link below **or** enter this code in the application: XXYYXX

...that way the user can do whichever they want and they find comfortable.

In case the user cancels the procedure, and then restarts the application, they will have the option to either create the account again, or click "I already have a code", whereupon they will be prompted to enter the code from the email.

Comment: So registration on web and then finishing the activation with mobile app is ok for you? Other way round, user register with mobile app and dialog awaiting activation code is shown until he enter the code. Then he finish the registration in browser. When he returns to mobile app the dialog requesting the activation is still opened. For me personally the "I have code" option is perfectly valid, for cases when you leave the application during the activation process.

Comment: Make it simple: all ways forward, straight or criss-crossing, all on one go or pausing and coming back, should be catered to.